# Target div class within by div id

Tags: jquery

This is the div structure

```
<div id="parnet1">
   <div id="subParnet1">
     <img src="smiley.png" class="faces">
   </div>
</div>
<div id="parnet2">
   <div id="subParnet2">
     <img src="sadf.png" class="faces">
   </div>
</div>
<div id="parnet3">
   <div id="subParnet3">
     <img src="grumpy.png" class="faces">
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to make grumpy.png invisible using jQuery. Below is what I tried. Doesn't work.

```
$('#subParnet3').find('.faces').css('display', 'none');
```

Comment: You can use `.hide()` apart from that no issue

Comment: That looks just right.

Comment: your code already works ,,, see this https://jsfiddle.net/sw91q0vk/14/

Answer (score 0):

Works well with jQuery:

```js
$('#subParnet3').find('.faces').css('display', 'none');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parnet1">
  <div id="subParnet1">
    <img src="smiley.png" class="faces">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="parnet2">
  <div id="subParnet2">
    <img src="sadf.png" class="faces">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="parnet3">
  <div id="subParnet3">
    <img src="grumpy.png" class="faces">
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also use `.hide()`:

```js
$('#subParnet3').find('.faces').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parnet1">
  <div id="subParnet1">
    <img src="smiley.png" class="faces">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="parnet2">
  <div id="subParnet2">
    <img src="sadf.png" class="faces">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="parnet3">
  <div id="subParnet3">
    <img src="grumpy.png" class="faces">
  </div>
</div>
```

See `grumpy.png` is hidden. Check if some CSS has `!important` in them or if you have forgot to include jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is just fine. Did you include the

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

in your file? This might cause your problem. If not, I suggest trying with `$('#subParnet3').find('.faces').hide();`, this hides the child with the `faces` class.

After including the google/microsoft lib, you should have something like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#subParnet3').find('.faces').hide();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#subParnet3').find('.faces').css('display', 'none');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parnet1">
  <div id="subParnet1">
    <img src="smiley.png" class="faces">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="parnet2">
  <div id="subParnet2">
    <img src="sadf.png" class="faces">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="parnet3">
  <div id="subParnet3">
    <img src="grumpy.png" class="faces">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide some context eg. explain what your code does